# traefik configuration for netdata on docker

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik, netdata

I am struggling configuring traefik:v2.6 so I can access a self-hosted [netdata](https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/installation/installation-methods/docker) instance running on docker. This is my compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  netdata:
    image: netdata/netdata
    volumes:
      - "netdataconfig:/etc/netdata"
      - "netdatalib:/var/lib/netdata"
      - "netdatacache:/var/cache/netdata"
      - "/etc/passwd:/host/etc/passwd:ro"
      - "/etc/group:/host/etc/group:ro"
      - "/proc:/host/proc:ro"
      - "/sys:/host/sys:ro"
      - "/etc/os-release:/host/etc/os-release:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.rule=Host(`netdata.$myserver`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.netdata.loadbalancer.server.port=19999"
      - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    networks:
      - proxy
volumes:
  netdataconfig:
  netdatalib:
  netdatacache:
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

When I try to access netdata via `netdata.$myserver` I see the backdrop only but no dashboard:

[image: netdata_without_dashboard]

Checking developer settings in Firefox reveal the following message:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://netdata.$myserver/dashboard-react.js”. [netdata.$myserver:16:1](http://netdata.$myserver/)
Uncaught ReferenceError: NETDATA is not defined
    225 main.js:435
    p (index):16
    566 main.7d1bdca1.chunk.js:2
    p (index):16
    324 main.7d1bdca1.chunk.js:2
    p (index):16
    f (index):16
    e (index):16
    <anonymous> main.7d1bdca1.chunk.js:2
```

The [documentation](https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/deployment-in-production/secure-your-nodes/reverse-proxies/nginx) has templates for several reverse proxy configurations, but I cannot translate them into settings I might have missed for traefik.

I tried adding a `&& Path('/netdata')` to the rule `traefik.http.routers.netdata.rule=Host('netdata.$myserver')"` but there was no difference. The traefik dashboard does not show any errors related to netdata. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Subpath like /netdata you have to call the directory with a slash at the end, then it will work.

```
 labels:
   - "traefik.enable=true"
   - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.entrypoints=web"
   - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.rule=Host(`yourdomain`) && PathPrefix(`/netdata`)"
   - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.service=netdata"
   - "traefik.http.services.netdata.loadbalancer.server.port=19999"
   - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.middlewares=netdatapathstrip"
   - "traefik.http.middlewares.netdatapathstrip.stripprefix.prefixes=/netdata"
```

I can reach the dashboard under http://yourdomain/netdata/
If I call http://yourdomain/netdata I get the same behaviour as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a subdomain.
That Host value needs to actually resolve to something.
(as in the dns needs to be setup or be added to the docker host machine's /etc/hosts file.)

Here's my docker-compose file which is almost verbatim from the netdata documentation.

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  traefikweb:
    external: true

services:
  netdata:
    image: netdata/netdata
    container_name: netdata
    pid: host
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.ports=19999"
      - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.rule=Host(`netdata.traefik.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.netdata.tls=true"   
    networks:
      - traefikweb
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
      - SYS_ADMIN
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    volumes:
      - netdataconfig:/etc/netdata
      - netdatalib:/var/lib/netdata
      - netdatacache:/var/cache/netdata
      - /etc/passwd:/host/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/host/etc/group:ro
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /etc/os-release:/host/etc/os-release:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  netdataconfig:
  netdatalib:
  netdatacache:
```

Comment: My subdomain does resolve - how else am I getting the backdrop when connecting. This started to work without any changes to my config after netdata update to 1.40.

Comment: Issue reported here: https://github.com/netdata/netdata/issues/14709
Fixed in 1.41